# confluence macro: get space administrators

Tags: macros, confluence

Trying to develop a macro wherein if user provides key then following should process:
1. Validate if key is present and show space title
2. Get the space administrators.

Got macro's from google, able to perform 2nd, but 1st is tricky to check (new to macro and confluence

```
## Macro title: Space Administrators
## Macro has a body: Y or N (N)
## Body processing: Selected body processing option
## Output: Selected output option
## usage: {getspacekey: spacekey1}
## Installed by: Piyush Annadate

## Macro to list all users and groups with the permission to administer the     current space.
## @param 0:title=Space Key|type=string|required=true

#if ($param0)
## trim and test for illegal characters
#set ($spacekey1= $param0.trim())
#if ($spacekey1.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+"))

    <h1>Space Adminstrators</h1>

    <p>The following users and groups have permission to administer the <strong>$spacekey1</strong> Space.</p>

    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table class="confluenceTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="confluenceTh">Space Administrators</th>
      </tr>
      #foreach ($permission in $space.getPermissions())
        #if ($permission.isUserPermission() && $permission.getType() == "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS")
          <tr>
            <td class="confluenceTd">#usernameLink($permission.getUserName())</td>
          </tr>
      #end
    #end
    </table>

    <h2>Groups</h2>
    #foreach ($permission in $space.getPermissions())
      #if ($permission.isGroupPermission() && $permission.getType() == "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS")
        #set ( $groupString = $permission.getGroup() )
        #set ( $groupObject = $userAccessor.getGroup($groupString) )
        #set ( $memberList = $userAccessor.getMemberNamesAsList($groupObject) )

        <h3>$groupString</h3>
        <table class="confluenceTable">
          <tr>
            <th class="confluenceTh">Space Administrators</th>
          </tr>


          #foreach ($member in $memberList)
            <tr>
              <td class="confluenceTd">#usernameLink($member)</td>
            </tr>
          #end
        </table>
      #end
    #end
#else
  Space key {color:red} is invalid.Space key is not available or does not matched a-z, A-Z, 0-9 pattern. {color}
#end
#end
```

Answer (score 0):

Added conditions to get space key and match n validate

```
## Macro title: Space Administrators
## Macro has a body: Y or N (N)
## Body processing: Selected body processing option
## Output: Selected output option
##
## Developed by(Modified): Piyush Annadate
## Date Installed: 03/03/2017
## Installed by: Piyush Annadate

## Macro to list all users and groups with the permission to administer the current space.

##Changes done: Added conditions:
## @param TargetSpace:title=Target space|type=string|desc=Enter the KEY of the space you want admin details for. For example, coredoc, gscontent, samples, wncontent|required=true|multiple=false

## trim and test for illegal characters
#set ($paramTargetSpace= $param0.trim())
#set ( $targetSpace = $spaceManager.getSpace($paramTargetSpace))
#if ((!$paramTargetSpace.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")) && !$targetSpace)
    Space key is {color:red}invalid{color}.Provided key does not matched a-z, A-Z, 0-9 pattern. 
#end
#if (($paramTargetSpace.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")) && !$targetSpace)
    No space exists with <strong>$paramTargetSpace</strong> key.
#end
##END OF CHANGES 
#if ($targetSpace)
    <h1>Space Adminstrators</h1>

    <p>The following users and groups have permission to administer the <strong>$space.getName()</strong> Space.</p>

    <h2>Users</h2>
    <table class="confluenceTable">
      <tr>
        <th class="confluenceTh">Space Administrators</th>
      </tr>
      #foreach ($permission in $targetSpace.getPermissions())
        #if ($permission.isUserPermission() && $permission.getType() == "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS")
          <tr>
            <td class="confluenceTd">#usernameLink($permission.getUserName())</td>
          </tr>
      #end
    #end
    </table>

    <h2>Groups</h2>
    #foreach ($permission in $targetSpace.getPermissions())
      #if ($permission.isGroupPermission() && $permission.getType() == "SETSPACEPERMISSIONS")
        #set ( $groupString = $permission.getGroup() )
        #set ( $groupObject = $userAccessor.getGroup($groupString) )
        #set ( $memberList = $userAccessor.getMemberNamesAsList($groupObject) )

        <h3>$groupString</h3>
        <table class="confluenceTable">
          <tr>
            <th class="confluenceTh">Space Administrators</th>
          </tr>


          #foreach ($member in $memberList)
            <tr>
              <td class="confluenceTd">#usernameLink($member)</td>
            </tr>
          #end
        </table>
      #end
    #end
#end
```

Comment: Please explain in short words what you've changed.